# Undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass (when trying to validate REST token acceptation)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, magento, oauth, token

I'm trying to validate Magento REST Api tokens with using Ruby oauth client.
I'm working on Windows 7, Ruby 2.2.0 (Magento 1.7.0.2 hosted on Ubuntu distant server).

1) I execute through CLI the following command:

```
oauth --verbose --query-string --consumer-key ABCD --consumer-secret ABCD --access-token -url https://www.mywebsite.com/ch_fr/oauth/token --authorize-url https://www.mywebsite.com/ch_fr/admin/oauth_authorize --request-token-url mywebsite.com/ch_fr/oauth/initiate authorize
```

Note: urls in my command are all starting with "https://www" (my low rep on stackoverflow prevents me to post more than 2 urls).

2) The ruby client display the following message:

```
Server appears to support OAuth 1.0a; enabling support.
Please visit this url to authorize:
https://www.mywebsite.com/ch_fr/admin/oauth_authorize?oauth_token=ABCD
Please enter the verification code provided by the SP (oauth_verifier):
```

3) After successfully connecting to the oauth_authorize url, login, accept the token and receive the verifier code, I fill the code in my shell Windows + press Enter.

Then, here is my problem, the following message appears:

```
RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1532:in `addr_port': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMet
Error)
     from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1465:in `begin_transport'
     from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1410:in `transport_request'
     from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1384:in `request'
     from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1377:in `block in request'
     from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:853:in `start'
     from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1375:in `request'
     from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/oauth-0.5.1/lib/oauth/consumer.rb:161:in `request'
     from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/oauth-0.5.1/lib/oauth/consumer.rb:195:in `token_reques

     from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/oauth-0.5.1/lib/oauth/tokens/request_token.rb:20:in `g
access_token'
     from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/oauth-0.5.1/lib/oauth/cli.rb:80:in `execute'
     from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/oauth-0.5.1/lib/oauth/cli.rb:19:in `execute'
     from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/oauth-0.5.1/bin/oauth:5:in `<top (required)>'
     from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/bin/oauth:23:in `load'
     from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/bin/oauth:23:in `<main>'
```

Is something sent by my Magento server wrongly received by Ruby (e.g. "nil" value)?
Is the verifier code not correctly sent to my Magento server?
Or is it something wrong with my Ruby installation?
An other point?

Note 2: I'm new on Ruby ;)

Any help would be appreciate.
Thx in advance.

Comment: It would greatly help if you would paste the ruby code you use to connet to your REST API. I'm guessing (from the error message) that the url you are trying to connect to is not a fully-formed url (So it has for example only `/admin/oauth_/xxx`

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is related to the url that you call, the error below is because you call Net::HTTP.new(url,nil) and the library doesn't like a nil port.
I think you need to fix the url to add the port and try again.